# Open MS Access subform to edit specific record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access form "DailyItemsTracked" with a subform "ActivitiesSubform" in datasheet view. When I double click on a record in "ActivitiesSubform" it should be opening a form called "ActivityEntry" to edit the record.

When I double click, I have the correct id of the record I want to edit. However, the new form consistently opens to add a new record rather than edit the existing record. (All existing records are filtered out). I have Googled the issue for more than an hour, but without a resolution.

The name of the id field and the id control source on the popup form are both "id".

Here is how I have tried to open the form:

```
MsgBox (Me![id]) 'It is getting the correct id for the selected record

DoCmd.OpenForm "ActivityEntry", , , "ID=" & Me.id

DoCmd.OpenForm "ActivityEntry", , , "[id]=" & Me![id]

DoCmd.OpenForm "ActivityEntry", , , "[id]=" & Form_ActivitiesSubform.id

Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
stDocName = "ActivityEntry"
stLinkCriteria = "[id]=" & Me![id]

Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
stDocName = "ActivityEntry"
stLinkCriteria = "ActivityEntryEdit.[id]= " & Me![id]
```

Even when I spell out the id explicitly it is still opening to a new record:

```
Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
stDocName = "ActivityEntry"
stLinkCriteria = "ActivityEntry.[id]= " & 69
```

Nor can I select the record after opening

```
Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
stDocName = "ActivityEntry"
stLinkCriteria = "ActivityEntryEdit.[id]= " & Me![id]
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
Forms(stDocName).Recordset.FindFirst "id = " & Me!id
```

I appreciate any help you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the syntax of the `DoCmd.OpenForm` statement. You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx). Short answer, you need to set the `DataMode` parameter to `acFormEdit`.