# Access 2010 trying to edit RichText Field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

**The problem:**

The User should be Able to edit a RTF formated Text with a Textfieldcontroll in Access 2010, the RTF should be updated into a table with a varbinary(max) column, (Sql Server 2008 R2

**My Solution So Far:**

First: User clicks "edit entry" button, which triggers the following code:

```
...
DoCmd.OpenForm "theRtfEditForm", , , stLinkCriteria, , , args
...
```

Second:the form is fired up, and the following code is executed (onload-event):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim TheRowiWantToEdit As String

If (Me.OpenArgs <> "" And Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs)) Then
TheRowiWantToEdit = OpenArgs
End If

Dim query As String
query = "select top 1  theColumnIWantToEdit from TableFoo where id = " & TheRowiWantToEdit
Me.recordsource = query
Me.Requery


End Sub
```

now i can type in Text, and even format it, although i cannot set the text alignment(but thats a different story). And it also gets updated to my sql database everything is ok,

but there is one problem:

in the lower left corner of the form there is the recordselector, saying: 1 of 1, and when i hit enter while editing my rtf, it will jump to record 2 of 2. Now, when i enter something and then hit enter, it will say:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AColumnINeverselectedInMyQuery', table 'TableFoo'; colmn does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Now i made some Reseach on Stackoverflow, and discowered this thread:
[VBA-manipulate field with subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886866/open-ms-access-subform-to-edit-specific-record)

Also i considered [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191834.aspx) site on microsoft.com.

But my problem is: i want my users to just be able to edit existing records, not to add new ones. And also i have carefully preselected just one record so the recordselector is completely useless in my case, and yes i tried to set Formproperties-> Recordselectors to "no", but its not working.

Other then that, the editing works, if the user does not press enter, but whats the point of having a Textfield when you cannot make paragraphs?

**My Question in Essence:**

How to Display/Edit just this one Record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the statement

```
Me.AllowAdditions = False
```

to the `Form_Load()` code. That should prevent the user from inadvertently moving to a "New Record".